# Prevent double clicked SH script from being entered into ZSH history on Mac

Tags: mac, command-line, script, zsh

I've got some SH scripts which I double click to run.  The scripts run as intended, after having set the working directory via `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` at the beginning of the script, but every time I double click the script to run it, it gets added to my ZSH history with  `; exit;` added to the end.  I.e.:

```
/Users/ubiquibacon/my_script.sh ; exit;
```

Per the comments in `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` I created `~/.zshenv` and added `SHELL_SESSIONS_DISABLE=1` and `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` in an attempt to disable this "feature" but I've seen no difference in any terminal or SH script behavior based on these environment variables being set.

Comment: I don't understand how this effect could happen in the first place, but I would consider using `setopt no_share_history`.